# What is the purpose of the y parameter in this code?

Tags: haskell

This Haskell code prints out `[0,10,20,30,40,50]` but I don't understand what the `y` is suppose to do in the third line.

```
f [] = []
f [x] = [x]
f (x:y:xs) = x : f xs
main = print (f [0,5..50])
```

Why doesn't it print the same result if I say  `f (x:xs) = x : f xs` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern in `f (x:y:xs)` is saying: get the input to the function, assign the first element of the list to `x`, the second to `y` and the rest (tail) of the list to `xs`. And this function is returning the first element `x` followed by the result of applying `f` to `xs`. In essence, you are removing every second element from the list.

Answer (score 6):

`(x:y:xy)` is matching a list with at least two elements and binding `x` to the first element, `y` to the second and `xs` to the tail of the list.

By calling `x: f xs` the second element is removed from the resulting list.

As this value is never used, it doesn't need to be called `y` at all.

```
f [] = []
f [x] = [x]
f (x:_:xs) = x : f xs

main = print (f [0,5..50])
```

If you had instead written:

```
f [] = []
f [x] = [x]
f (x:xs) = x : f xs

main = print (f [0,5..50])
```

The result would just be the original list, as that second element is never "dropped."